# Use the definition of the integral to prove that if $A \subset E$, where $E$ is measurable, then $\int_A f = \int_E f \chi_{A}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I want to prove:

If $A \subset E$, where $E$ is measurable, then $\int_A f = \int_E f \chi_{A}$, where $f$ is a bounded measurable function and $m(E) < 
\infty$

**Solution:**

Let $f: E \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded measurable function on $E$, where $E$ has finite measure. Let $A \subset E$ to be measurable as well. Notice that $f\chi_A$ is integrable if the the following holds.
$$\int_E f\chi_A = \sup\{\int_E\varphi: \varphi\text{ is simple and } \varphi \leq f\chi_A\} = \inf\{\int_E\psi: \psi\text{ is simple and } f\chi_A \leq \psi\},$$
and $f$ is integrable over $A$ if 
$$\int_A f = \sup\{\int_A\varphi: \varphi\text{ is simple and } \varphi \leq f\} = \inf\{\int_A\psi: \psi\text{ is simple and } f \leq \psi\}.$$
Now,
$$f\chi_A = \begin{cases}
f & \text{ if } x\in A, \\ 
0 & \text{ if } x \in E\sim A, 
\end{cases}$$
and notice that for each $x \in E\sim A$, we have $f = 0$, but if $f$ is integrable we must have that the supremum and infinimum of simple functions coincide, thus the condition $$ x \in E\sim A \text{ implies that } \varphi \leq 0  \text{ and } 0\leq \psi,$$
and $\varphi = 0 = \psi$ if we want $f\chi_A$ to be integrable over $E$. But this means that we only need to consider the restriction $f|_A$, that is,
$$f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$$
and in this case we have
$$\int_E f\chi_A = \int_Af\chi_A = \int_A f,$$
as required. To see this, notice that for $f$ restricted to $A$, we have,
$$\int_E f\chi_A = \sup\{\int_A\varphi: \varphi\text{ is simple and } \varphi \leq f\chi_A\} = \inf\{\int_A\psi: \psi\text{ is simple and } f\chi_A \leq \psi\},$$
but for every $x \in A$, we have that $\chi_A = 1$, therefore 
$$\int_E f\chi_A = \sup\{\int_A\varphi: \varphi\text{ is simple and } \varphi \leq f\} = \inf\{\int_A\psi: \psi\text{ is simple and } f \leq \psi\} = \int_A f.$$
Is this solution correct?

Comment: You have to have that $A$ is measurable as well. You need $f$ to be integrable too.

Answer (score 7):

By definition $\int_E f=\int f\chi_E$. So by definition $$\int_E f\chi_A=\int f\chi_A\chi_E=\int f\chi_A=\int_Af,$$because $\chi_A\chi_E=\chi_A$.

Comment: I am not understanding your argument. I tried to modify my aproach but not sure if it is correct.

Comment: What part don't you understand? The definitions or the fact that $\chi_A\chi_E=\chi_A$?

Comment: Yesterday I didn't see what aspect of the argument you could be failing to follow. Today I have a conjecture: Perhaps when I said that $\int_Ef=\int\chi_E f$ by definition you thought I meant that that followed from some definition and you didn't see how? If so: No, what I meant by that is that the equation $\int_Ef=\int\chi_Ef$ is the definition of $\int_E f$.

Comment: I have some questions: 1- why is $f$ measurable on $A$? ...... 2- why is $f \circ \chi_{A}$  measurable? .......3- How can we prove that for simple functions we have $\int_{A}  \psi = \int_{E} \psi \circ \chi_{A}$? ....... could you please include those details in your answer? Thanks!

Comment: @Intuition Why is $f$ measurable on $A$? I don't see how that has any relevance to the proof. Why is $f\circ\chi_A$ measurable? That's definititely irrelevant; there is no $f\circ\chi_A$ anywhere. What matters is that $f\chi_A$ is measurable, which holds simply because the product of two measurable functions is measurable. And the question about integrals of simple functions is definitely irrelevant.

Comment: @Intuition Your questions mostly seem to be questions about a totally different proof. What I posted was not intended to be an explanation of why the stuff in the original  question works. The _definition_ of $\int_Ef$ is $\int_Ef=\int f\chi_E$; that makes the question you asked literally trivial, just because $\chi_A\chi_E=\chi_A$. If you have any questions that are actually questions about the proof I gave I can answer them.

Comment: @Intuition The proof I gave consists of exactly two sentences. If you have a question you should clarify which of those two sentences you're asking about.

Comment: Could you explain why $\chi_{A} \chi_{E} = \chi_{A}$?

Comment: $\chi_A\chi_E(x)=1\iff \chi_A(x)=1\land\chi_E(x)=1\iff x\in A\land x\in E\iff x\in A\iff\chi_A(x)=1$ (since $A\subset E$.)

Comment: In _Real Analysis_, fourth edition, Royden and Fitzpatrick define the Lebesgue integral as okie does at the beginning of his solution.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $$\int_{E} f \chi_{A} \, d\mu = \int_{E \setminus A} f \chi_{A} \, d\mu + \int_{A} f \, d\mu,$$ so it suffices to show that $$\int_{E \setminus A} f \chi_{A} \, d\mu = 0.$$

This can be done rather easily by the definitions.

Comment: I modified the title, because I am only allowed to use the definition of the integral. I need to use the result in the question to prove the relation solution you give, sorry for the misunderstanding of the title.

Comment: I have some questions: 1- why is $f$ measurable on $A$? ...... 2- why is $f \circ \chi_{A}$  measurable? .......3- How can we prove that for simple functions we have $\int_{A}  \psi = \int_{E} \psi \circ \chi_{A}$? ....... could you please include those details in your answer? Thanks!